# Polynomial of polynomials (from Brilliant.org)

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

> **Moderator Note:** This is a [current question on brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/i/56cpu4/)

if f(x) is a polynomial satisfying $$27 f(x^3) -4f(x^2) - x^6 f(3x) + 46 = 0 ,$$ what is $f(10)$?

We can get $$f(0)=-2,\quad f(1)=f(-1)=-\displaystyle\frac{3}{2},\quad f(3)=f(-3)=\displaystyle\frac{23}{2}.$$

Can we say that for all the values?

Comment: @CalvinLin,  this is from https://brilliant.org

Comment: This is a problem posed on [Brilliant.org](brilliant.org). You may view the problem [here](https://brilliant.org/i/56cpu4/), and test your numerical answers. Moderators, please close this discussion for a week. Thanks. - Calvin Lin, Brilliant challenge Master

Comment: @CalvinLin Link parsing didn't work. You want the **www** I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: find out the highest order from $27f(x^3)-x^6f(3x)$ can cancel the leading term.